# How to use preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I have an application which needs a continue function. When the user for example presses the home button i need the application to store some information and then when the continue button is pressed for it to restart the application from exactly where it left off.

How can i do this? I've done some research on preferences but i seem to be getting conflicting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to actually save and retrieve their info, here's how to Save info

```
//save their info
        SharedPreferences settingsSave = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsSave.edit();
        editor.putString("someValue", theValue);

        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
```

And here's how to get it back

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
    installID = settings.getString("someValue", "");
```

You can then use this value to determine which view to start them at when they load your app.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Store your information on the onStop, and pull it out on the onResume. (or when relevant changes are made)

Comment: OnStop by that do you mean when the finish() method is called.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html OnStop is called on an activity as it leaves the foreground either through termination or another activity (such as the home screen) taking over.